# vb.net get file names in directory?

Tags: vb.net, file

I have the following code.

```
Dim text As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Example.xtp")
```

This code is specific to a single file, however I would like to `file.readalltext` for every file in a particular directory.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 49):

You will need to use the [IO.Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles) function.

```
Dim files() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\")

For Each file As String In files
  ' Do work, example
  Dim text As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(file)
Next
```

Answer (score 17):

```
Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles("YourPath", "*.txt")
' Process the list of .txt files found in the directory. '
Dim fileName As String

For Each fileName In fileEntries
    If (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName)) Then
        'Read File and Print Result if its true
        ReadFile(fileName)
    End If
    TransfereFile(fileName, 1)
Next
```

Answer (score 5):

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()
```

could help

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Dim text As String = ""
Dim files() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(sFolder)

For Each sFile As String In files
    text &= IO.File.ReadAllText(sFile)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public PathsAll As String 'is All Path Finded
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim BeginPath As String = "D:\" 'this is Begin Path
    FilesSearch(BeginPath)
    'TextBox1.Text = AddPath
End Sub
Public Sub FilesSearch(BeginPath As String)
    Dim arrFolders(0) As String
    Dim TmpDir As String
    Dim arrFiles As String
    Dim countDir As Integer = 0
    arrFolders(countDir) = ""
    If Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(BeginPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        BeginPath = BeginPath & "\"
    End If
    TmpDir = Dir(BeginPath, vbDirectory)
    ' On Error Resume Next
    Do While TmpDir <> ""
        AppendFiles(BeginPath & TmpDir)
        If TmpDir <> "." And TmpDir <> ".." Then
            If (GetAttr(BeginPath & TmpDir) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
                arrFolders(countDir) = BeginPath & TmpDir & "\"
                countDir += 1
                ReDim Preserve arrFolders(countDir)
            End If
        End If
        TmpDir = Dir()
    Loop
    arrFiles = Dir(BeginPath)
    Do Until arrFiles = ""
        arrFiles = Dir()
    Loop
    For X = 0 To (UBound(arrFolders) - 1)
        FilesSearch(arrFolders(X))
    Next X
End Sub
Public Sub AppendFiles(InPath As String)
    PathsAll += vbNewLine & InPath
End Sub
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: hi.It pours all the way into the string.