# VB How Do I Get A List of Files in a Specified Directory

Tags: vb.net

I think this is a simple question but I can't get the statement format working. I want to list all the files in a specified directory and sub-directories in a list box. I know this is pretty basic. I searched on the Microsoft doc site and I believe that I want to use the GetFile method below. My problem is that I don't know where I put the directory name.

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(
  My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments)

    listBox1.Items.Add(foundFile)
Next
```

Comment: You would replace `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments` with the directory.

Comment: Wow! You folk are talking over my head. What I hear for sure is that my For statement should be For Each foundFile As String in (My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(C:\mypath), correct? Where do I put the options you're talking about? Are they properties of my ListBox1 or what? What I would like to end up with is the full path and file name on a line for each file in the directory and sub-directories.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vb.net get file names in directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670750/vb-net-get-file-names-in-directory)

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Dim folderPath As String 'Set folder path here
Dim folder As New DirectoryInfo(folderPath)
Dim files = folder.GetFiles()

With listBox1
    .DisplayMember = "Name"
    .ValueMember = "FullName"
    .DataSource = files
End With
```

Pretty much always bind as a first option. Adding item by item is generally inferior. The `DisplayMember` is the property or column to display and the `ValueMember` is the property or column to expose via the control's `SelectedValue`. You can set the `folderPath` to whatever you want, however you want, e.g. let the user choose using a `FolderBrowserDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

Send all the file names of a directory to a text file :

```
    Imports System.IO
    'no need:
    'Imports System.Linq

    Dim MyFiles As String()
    MyFiles = Directory.GetFiles(MyPath).
        Select(Function(f) Path.
        GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)).ToArray()
        ' or WITH extension:
        ' GetFileName
    File.WriteAllLines(MyPath & "Text.txt", MyFiles)
```

Comment: This answer is quite confusing. The upper section, it appears you're choosing one or possibly two Imports statements. The lower section appears very incomplete. If you cannot fix this Answer yourself, can you explain what you meant here in comments so someone else can clean it up?

Comment: ”no need: Imports System.Linq”　It is not necessary.

Comment: I edited your Answer to make it less confusing by putting your inline notes into code comments. Please verify that I have not changed your meaning.